# UIDatePicker without "hour" label

Tags: timer, label, uidatepicker, hour

UIDatePicker in CountDownTimer mode shows the labels like this : 4 hours | 12 mins
How can you customize to look like this : 4 | 12 mins ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIDatePicker` does not allow this.  You could conceivably create your own date picker using a specialized `UIPickerView` and do it that way, but it'd be a fair amount of work.  If you'd like this ability on `UIDatePicker`, please [file a bug requesting it](https://bugreport.apple.com).